# My XML layout is not visible in the Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

This is my first app, and I am sure I am missing something obvious but I can't figure it out - any and all help appreciated!

I have got a very basic `XML` layout with an `EditText` view  in a `LinearLayout`.  It is showing correctly in the `XML` preview but when I try to run it in the emulator to test the input, nothing is shown.

I have tried deleting the background resource I created for the `EditText` border, and checking the `layout_width` / `layout_height` but nothing seems to be working.

Here is my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PlayerOneName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:hint="Player 1 Name"
        android:inputType="text"></EditText>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @HarperLozz Paste your java code here.

Comment: there isn't anything other than the default in the java code:  package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}

Comment: Thanks @BhoomikaPatel when I went to check the java, I realised the onCreate method was missing.  I have put it back and it works.

Comment: @HarperLozz if this helps you, then upvote comment, so others person can also find this useful.

Comment: @HarperLozz if this helps you, then upvote comment, so others person can also find this useful.